# Perl. Формат строки с числом

Tags: perl

Есть строки (пример):

> 4455232
>   8798798324893274
>   74562846248376

Необходимо привести их к виду:

> 4 455 232
>   8 798 798 324 893 274
>   74 562 846 248 376

т.е. с конца строки через каждые **3** символа вставить пробел.
Не получается сделать изящно.

Не самый красивый вариант:

```
my $s = "23456779732984729374928748";
my $m = length($s)%3 ? 3 - length($s)%3 : 0 ;
my $ss = join(' ', ((' 'x$m . $s) =~ m/.../g));
$ss =~ s/^\s+//g;
print "$ss\n";
```

Правильный вариант (спасибо [andy.37](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/192530/andy-37)):

```
my $s = '1923456723456779732984729374928748';
$s =~ s/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+$)/$1 /g;
print "$s\n";
```

Comment: Не очень понятно, причём здесь сортировка. Наверное, стоит переименовать вопрос и убрать тег **сортировка**. По поводу вопроса: для вставки разделителя тысяч можно использовать класс [Number::Format](http://search.cpan.org/~wrw/Number-Format-1.75/Format.pm).

Comment: Спасибо за вариант, но малость не то

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my $s = "12345678";
my $m = length($s)%3 ? 3 - length($s)%3 : 0 ;
my $ss = join(' ', ((' 'x$m . $s) =~ m/.../g));
print "$ss\n";
```

Работает, но добавляет в начало 0, 1 или 2 пробела (выравнивет длину первоначальной строки до 3N символов). Лидирующие пробелы убрать несложно.

П.С. демонов не вызывает, диск не форматирует)))

2-ой способ:
http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=110137. В целом то же самое, только дважды используется `reverse`, чтобы разделять по 3 символа с конца, а не с начала. Самый элегантный способ оттуда:

```
my $s = '1234567';
$s =~ s/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+$)/$1 /g;
```

Думаю, этот способ должен быть в упомянутой книге.

Comment: Спасибо за вариант
В решение добвил еще удаление лишнего пробела в начале

Answer (score 0):

```
my $l = '8798798324893274';
print join(' ', unpack('a'x(length ($l) % 3).'(a3)*', $l));
```

Answer (score -1):

Открываете классическую книгу по регулярным выражениям - [Джеффри Фридл
Регулярные выражения. 3-е издание](http://www.books.ru/books/regulyarnye-vyrazheniya-3-e-izdanie-592346/) и там в второй главе на 88 (эта страница для второго издания) странице есть целый раздел, посвященный этому вопросу.